# I am trying to upload my Overleaf project to PRISM Optica system but says "Compressed File must include one TeX file". Even when TEX is inside

Tags: overleaf

Hi I am trying to upload a paper to the PRISM system (former OSA now Optica). I prepared everything with their suggested overleaf template, I downloaded the project and tried to upload but it gives me the error: "Compressed File must include one TeX file". I checked the zip and it has a TEX file, so I wonder what might be happening.

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to TSE. This doesn't seem to be a question about LaTeX.

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) As José says, this question is probably better directed to Overleaf or OSA support. In this case, I would recommend contacting OSA first – this is because we Overleaf support staff cannot see the internal state of your submission on PRISM, only OSA staff can. If they recommend some changes to your Overleaf project to address this, but you're unable to make those changes yourself, then please write to us at support@overleaf.com with your project's URL and the recommendations from OSA.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same error, you can check if you have more than one tex file in your zip.

Comment: Welcome. // Fair point: the question says, it contains "a" .tex file, not "1 and only 1 file".